# Examples of coupled 2nd time independent ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am seeking a system of two to four coupled ODEs which can be put together into one fourth order equation. That is, a system of two coupled 2nd order ODEs (this is preferred), but it would be fine if you recommended a system of four 1st order ODEs. Time independence is a must.

I was originally thinking about coupled harmonic oscillators but again,but I want to stay away from time evolving situations.

It would also be best if the system had some closed form analytical solution, or at least some analytical approximation. I will use whatever system people suggest, to test my numerical code, so it is of course better if I have something analytical to work with.

I've personally been thinking about some type of coupled Poisson type equations, something like

$\nabla F(r) = G(r)$, and $\nabla G(r) = F(r)$ , where $\nabla$ is the laplacian.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode.htm , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dynamical_systems_and_differential_equations_topics

Comment: @Amzoti, Unfortunately no, I myself was thinking about a coupled spring-mass type systems, but then I realized that I needed to stay away from evolution type ODEs. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Indeed google is friendly, and I went to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/OrdinaryDifferentialEquations.html  to find some ODEs, but nothing really jumped out at me. And to avoid clicking on a 100 or so links for individual differential equations (since most of the examples they provide are not for coupled systems) I came to stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most trivial example of 4th order system that can be put in one single ODE of 4th order. Consider 4th order system like this:

$\begin{align}
& x' = x_1 \\
& x_1' =x_2 \\
& x_2' = x_3 \\
& x_3' = -ax_3 -bx_2 -cx_1 - dx,
\end{align}$

which can be obtained from 4th order equation $x^{(4)} + ax^{(3)}+ bx^{(2)}+ cx^{(1)} + dx = 0$. Since this is a simple linear homogeneous ODE, the solution exists in closed form and can be computed exactly.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, this system is definitely something to look into.